# phpmyadmin alternative for django

Tags: mysql, django, phpmyadmin

When I start a new Django project I invariably end up installing a bunch of PHP related stuff I don't actively use but that are required (*I think*) for phpMyAdmin to work. I have no complaints about phpMyAdmin but as I work in a couple of PC's, I was wondering whether there is something to easily keep my databases (MySQL, by the way) synchronized.

Does anyone know of something like that?. Cross-platform software (Linux, Windows) would be ideal, but I'm open to alternatives.

Furthermore, what's the absolute minimum required to setup a MySQL database with Django?. `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` and `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`?

Thanks

Comment: Uh... phpMyAdmin doesn't keep databases synchronized. It's just a web interface to MySQL.

Comment: By the way, I don't want them to synchronize automatically (that would be great, though). Just that I don't have to do imports all the time to keep more or less the same information. By the way, I removed 'else' from 'something else'... I realized that could be confusing.

Comment: You can do SQL dumps via the command line. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Alright, but I feel that's very similar to phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Well, your question says "alternative" so you don't have to install PHP. If you're looking for something **better** that's another question entirely.

Comment: So similiar that you don't need a single php dependency ...
But it still don't get what you are exactly after? Do you want to copy the that database tables or are you concerned with syncing your schemas? For the first task i'd use fabric (http://nopper.archpwn.org/2010/08/09/backup-your-django-database-using-fabric/) to wrap my commands, for the second job south (http://south.aeracode.org/) is the de facto standard in djangoland.

Comment: _Do you want to copy the that database tables?_ Yes. Fabric looks good but it seems to be targeted to other uses. In that sense, mysqldump would be more or less the same in my case, but it's a good suggestion, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz Well, I rarely seek for an alternative which makes my life harder :-).

Comment: Nearly cross-platform (think via embeded wine for linux..) if you are looking for a desktop-application - [navicat](http://navicat.com) could be an option. It is not free tough, but has some nice tools, like data- and structure-synchronisation.

Answer (score 0):

Syncronisation is termed as replication for databases. Look at [This link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) for more information.